# Merge wine tray with gnome tray

Tags: gnome, wine, system-tray

Is there a way to merge wine system tray with standard tray in gnome instead of having two separate tray bars?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution at last. I needed:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+RightClick on panel
2. Select "Add to panel.."
3. Enable "Notification Area"

After that trays was automatically merged.